# No results in Music lens! Music files appear in File lens!

Tags: 12.04, unity, music, lenses

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Unity --- almost default install.

About two weeks back I populated my Music folder with a lot of music files (mp3s).

When I go to file lens (Super F), and search I get to see all the music files matching the criteria. The files have a Music file icon.

When I go to music lens (Super M), and search, I get NO results!

How can I get the 'normal', expected behavior?

Comment: OK. I disabled zeitgeist plugin in Rhythmbox (my default music player). Now, results have started appearing in Music lens. But the file lens still is crowded with the music results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Privacy, then go to Files tab, there is an option to select folder to do not register activity, add your music folder. Log out, come back and voilà.

And you don't need to disable the zeitgeist plugin of rhythmbox to show the music in the Music lens,because the Music lens works with the music library files that rhythmbox generates in  **~/.local/rhythmbox/**

Greetings!

Comment: Perfect. Now the Music lens shows all my music and File lens, the files.

But was not this how it was supposed to be without any user intervention??